# Flask-sqlalchemy add numbers on button click

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hai so i am trying to increase a number ( +1 ) in my join column on button click on flask so far i done up to this

```py
@app.route("/joins/<name>", methods=["POST"])
def joins(name):
    namess = name
    owner = users.query.filter_by(name=namess).first()
    if owner is not None:
        #making the joins +1 if the value is already 1            
        owner.joins = + 1
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return "You are not the owner of this url"
```

but it is not increasing the number how can i fix this happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```py
owner.joins = + 1
```

is valid python but I don't think it's what you want. It just assigns 1 to `owner.joins`. If you want to increment you need to do it like this:

```py
owner.joins = owner.joins + 1
```